# improve javascript animation to do it smooth and optimized

Tags: javascript

I need your help to improve my animation : it is a 3d hover effect on mouse move on some elements.

this animation is visually working but i'd like to improve it and optimize it (with requestAnimationFrame maybe ?) or something else, i'm a javascript novice and don't really understand how to do that...

there is a working exemple of my code, thanks for your help

```js
function mouseCoordinates(event, element) {
  const bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect()

  const centerX = bounds.left + bounds.width / 2
  const centerY = bounds.top + bounds.height / 2

  return {
    x: event.clientX - centerX,
    y: event.clientY - centerY
  }
}

function hover3d(event, element) {
  const coordinates = mouseCoordinates(event, element)

  let x = coordinates.x / 1000000
  let y = coordinates.y / 500000

  element.style.transform = 'matrix3d(1,0,0.00,' + x + ',0.00,1,0.00,' + y + ',0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)'
}

const tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile__wrapper')
tiles.forEach(tile => {
  tile.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    hover3d(e, this)
  })

  tile.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    this.style.transform = 'matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)'
  })
})
```

```css
.tiles {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.tile {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tile__wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tiles__item tile">
    <div class="tile__wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tiles__item tile">
    <div class="tile__wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tiles__item tile">
    <div class="tile__wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tiles__item tile">
    <div class="tile__wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a working example of your code (working demo)? Either online (codepen etc.) or directly here in your question with a code snippet?

Comment: Its better to add the example here on stackoverflow. So that this question can bennefit others at a later date.

Comment: Hello @JeremyThille, my code is on the answer, do you have any suggest ? thanks

Comment: Ah, you should have edited your original question. I moved your code snippet from the answer you made into your original question. You can delete the answer (because it's not one). Now, I had a look at this code, and it works well and I don't see any big optimization to be done!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tested this code on my main computer and it works well, but on my laptop there is lag, I do not understand why. If you have an idea it would be nice